# Calculate equation of normal line on any given point

Tags: calculus

I know there are alot of topics about this, but almost all of them cover the case when you are  given an explicit point like (3,6), but I need the general formula to solve for any given X and I'm a bit lost at the process of calculating it.

Here is what I did so far:

given f(x) = sin( x)

I would like to find the tangent ( and later the normal) for the point P=(x,sin(x))

I know that the normal line is perpendicular to the tangent line of that function, so first I calculate the slope of the tangent line of f(x), like so:

f'(x) = cos(x)

now that I have the slope of the tangent,I could try to find the equation for the tangent line using this:

y= m*x + b , and replacing...

y = cos(x) * x + b

and to get b :

sin(x) = cos(x) * x + b

then:

sin(x) - cos(x) * x = b

So the equation for the tangent line would be this:

y = cos(x) * x + sin(x) - cos(x) * x

As I said earlier ( according to my understanding) the normal line is perpendicular to the slope of the tangent line, so given two slopes:

m1= slope of tangent

m2= slope of normal

m1*m2 = -1 // To be perpendicular

finding m2:

m2 = -1/ cos(x)

SO, if all of the above is correct, the equation for the normal line would be:

y = (-1/cos(x)) * x + sin(x) - cos(x) * x

Did I do it right? And if so, how do I continue?

Thanks

PS: English is not my native language so my apologies if something isn't clear, just say it in the comments and I will try to explain it better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *very* close. You're using the symbol $x$ both for the first coordinate of the point at which you want to find the normal line *and*as the variable in the equation of the normal line. Let me rewrite:

Given $f(x) = \sin(x)$, compute the normal line at $(a, \sin(a))$. The slope of the tangent is $\cos(a)$, so the slope of the normal is $\frac{-1}{\cos a}, so the equation of the normal  is

$$
y = \frac{-1}{\cos a} (x - a) + Q
$$
where $Q$ is as yet unknown. But the point $x = a, y = \sin a$ must lie on this line, so we must have
$$
\sin a = \frac{-1}{\cos a} (a - a) + Q
$$
so $Q = \sin a$. Hence your equation is
$$
y = \frac{-1}{\cos (a)} (x - a) + \sin(a).
$$

Comment: Thanks  everyone for your quick answers, and I have one more question ( related to everyone's anwers), in our final equation we have "(x - a)", but I'm confused as to how do I get the X value ( I thought that the X value would be "a"). For example if I now plug the value a=0, what will the X value be ( so i can replace it and calculate Y) ? And sorry if this question needs a long answer, in that case I will post it as a new Question on the site. Thanks

Comment: The final answer I gave is the equation of a normal line that passes through the point $(a, \sin a)$. Because the line has many points, there are many pairs $(x, y)$ that make the equation true. For instance, if you plug in $(x, y) = (a, \sin a)$, you'll find that you get $\sin a = \sin a$, which is true, so this point is on the line. If you wanted to find the $x$-intercept (where $y = 0$), you'd write $0 =  \frac{-1}{\cos (a)} (x - a) + \sin(a)$ and solve for $x$, getting $x = a + \sin a \cos a$. If you wanted the $y$-intersept, you'd set $x$ to $0$ and get $y = \sin a - \frac{x}{\cos a}$.

Comment: thanks a lot , I think I've got it

Answer (score 1):

Your equation of the line will involve $y$ and $x$ as variables, presumably in roughly the form
$$y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$$
where $m$ is the gradient at that point. Let's call $x_0=a$ for brevity, and since the line will go through the curve$y=f(x)$, we have $y_0=f(a)$.

The last thing is $m$. We know the gradient of $f(x)$ is just $f'(x)$, and the gradient of the *tangent* at $a$ will be $f'(a)$ which is $\cos a$ in your example. The gradient of the normal will then be $m=\frac{-1}{f'(a)}$.

Putting this all together we get, at the point $(a,f(a))$ the equation of the normal is:

$$y-f(a)={-1\over f'(a)}(x-a)$$
or $$y=f(a)-{x-a \over f'(a)}$$

For your example, $f(x)=\sin x\implies f(a)=\sin a, f'(a)=\cos a$ and we get
$$y=\sin a-{x-a \over \cos a}$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we want the equation of the tangent line at a point $x_0$.  Then we know

$$\frac{y-\sin x_0 }{x-x_0}=\cos x_0$$

whereupon solving foyr $y$ gives

$$y=\sin x_0+\cos x_0(x-x_0)$$

or alternatively

$$y=(\cos x_0)\,x+(\sin x_0-x_0\cos x_0) $$

---

If we want the line normal to the sine function at $x_0$ then we write

$$\frac{y-\sin x_0 }{x-x_0}=-\sec x_0$$

whereupon solving foyr $y$ gives

$$y=\sin x_0-\sec x_0(x-x_0)$$

or alternatively

$$y=(-\sec x_0)\,x+(\sin x_0+x_0\sec x_0) $$